# Discord.py status does not show the member online status, but shows offline

Tags: discord.py

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGX60.png)I have a command that checks the info about a given player and bot. The last error is when showing activity and member, because when you enter a member that is available, it shows that he is unavailable.
I use this command: member.status

```
`client = discord.Client()
 intents = discord.Intents.default()
 intents.presences = True
 client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="q.", intents=intents)
 client.remove_command('help')
 
 @client.command()
async def getname(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
member = ctx.author if not member else member
roles = [role for role in member.roles]
embed = discord.Embed(
    clour=member.color, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, color=0x00ff00)
embed.set_author(name=f"Nazwa użytkownika: {member}")
embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
embed.set_footer(
    text=f"Utworzony {ctx.author}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
embed.add_field(name="ID", value=member.id)
embed.add_field(name="Pseudomin", value=member.display_name)
embed.add_field(
    name="Konto Utworzone:",
    value=member.created_at.strftime("%d.%m.%Y,%H:%M.%S"))
embed.add_field(
    name="Dołączył:", value=member.joined_at.strftime("%d.%m.%Y,%H:%M.%S"))
embed.add_field(
    name=f"Rola ({len(roles)})",
    value=" ".join([role.mention for role in roles]))
embed.add_field(name="Najwyższa rola", value=member.top_role.mention)
embed.add_field(name="Status", value=member.status)
embed.add_field(name="Aktywność", value=member.activity)
embed.add_field(name="Bot", value=member.bot)
embed.add_field(name="Status mobilny", value=member.mobile_status)
embed.add_field(name="Nitro", value=member.premium_since)
embed.add_field(name="Kolor nazwy", value=member.color)
embed.add_field(name="Kanał Głosowy", value=member.voice)
embed.add_field(name="Status na komputerze", value=member.desktop_status)
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

`

Comment: Do you have intents.presences enabled?

Comment: I do not have it turned on and is it due and should I put where I have the bot prefix set?

Comment: please include the error statement you're receiving for clarification

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGX60.png shows that the status of this user, as shown in the photo, is offline and not active.

Comment: You should replace `intents = discord.Intents.default()` to `intents = discord.Intents.all()` and make sure your intents are enabled in your discord application (https://discord.com/developers/applications/), in the `Bot` section.

Comment: I have it done and it still doesn't work as I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should activate the server members intents from the discord developer portal for your bot, then you must give your bot the accessibility like below:

```py
intents = discord.Intents(members = True, presences = True)

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="q.", intents=intents)
```

Comment: Ok, it works, but with some bots, users don't see messages or show offline status. I think I have to change something about the rights of my roles

Comment: Make sure to activate the messages intents and try to give the bot the fully permission (administrator) maybe this will fix, don't forget to activate the intents from the discord developer portal, and finally if non of them works read the docs.
`if my solution has fixed your problem you can mark it as  accepted`